# Highcharts VU Meter Gauge numeric display disapears

Tags: highcharts

An interesting little "quirk" using the sample of the VU gauge. When I try to reposition the gauge pane, the numeric display will just disappear. If I keep the position <= 100%, the display will show, anything > 100% and the numeric display is gone.

I have repeatedly tried to force the display back into a position where it can be seen, but no luck. Any ideas? Here is the latest test fiddle:

[VU Meter Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/Z2s77/11)

Adjusting the elements is easy, use the pane: section to move the entire gauge with the display pane, use the datalabel: section to move the numeric display.

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        plotBackgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
            stops: [
                [0, '#FFF4C6'],
                [0.3, '#FFFFFF'],
                [1, '#FFF4C6']
            ]
        },
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        height: 200
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Efficiencies'
    },
    /***
       in order to move the gauge up or down in the pane, adjust the 'Y' element in
       the center array. Adjusting this above 100% (to move the gauge DOWN) 
       will cause the numeric display to disappear
    ***/
    pane: [{
        startAngle: -45,
        endAngle: 45,
        background: null,
        center: ['25%', '100%'],
        size: 200
    }, {
        startAngle: -45,
        endAngle: 45,
        background: null,
        center: ['75%', '105%'],
        size: 200
    }],                        

    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        max: 110,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
            rotation: 'auto',
            distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 70,
            color: '#DF5353', // red
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
         }, {
            from: 70,
            to: 95,
             color: '#DDDF0D', // yellow
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
        }, {
            from: 95,
            to: 110,
            color: '#55BF3B', // green
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 0,
        title: {
            text: '<span style="font-size:10px">OEE %</span><br/><span style="font-size:8px">Machine 001</span>',
            y: -30
        }
    }, {
        min: 0,
        max: 110,
        minorTickPosition: 'outside',
        tickPosition: 'outside',
        labels: {
            rotation: 'auto',
            distance: 20
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 70,
            color: '#DF5353', // red
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
         }, {
            from: 70,
            to: 95,
             color: '#DDDF0D', // yellow
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
        }, {
            from: 95,
            to: 110,
            color: '#55BF3B', // green
            innerRadius: '100%',
            outerRadius: '105%'
        }],
        pane: 1,
        title: {
            text: '<span style="font-size:10px">Cycle Eff %</span><br/><span style="font-size:8px">Machine 001</span>',
            y: -30
        }
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        gauge: {
            /***
               Adjusting the position of the numeric display is also easy
               Change the y: component more negative move the display UP, 
               decreasing the value move the display DOWN
            ***/
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                x: 0,
                y: -120
            },
            dial: {
                radius: '110%'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [80],
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
        data: [80],
        yAxis: 1
    }]

},

// Let the music play
function(chart) {
    setInterval(function() {
        var left = chart.series[0].points[0],
            right = chart.series[1].points[0],
            leftVal, 
            //inc = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 30;
            inc1 = Math.random() * (30) + 70;
            inc2 = Math.random() * (30) + 70;

        leftVal =  left.y + inc1;
        rightVal = right.y + inc2; // / 3;
        if (leftVal < 0 || leftVal > 110) {
            //leftVal = left.y - inc;
            leftVal = 110 - inc1;
        }
        if (rightVal < 0 || rightVal > 110) {
            rightVal = 110 - inc2;
        }

        left.update(parseInt(leftVal),false);
        right.update(parseInt(rightVal), false);//, false);
        chart.redraw();

    }, 1500);

});
});
```

Comment: Reported issue on tracker, see: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the dataLabels.crop = false option it will show up. But based on the API description it will also show up if the data label is outside the plot area as well, which you may not want. The behavior by highcharts is weird though because it looks at whether the series is outside the plot area and not where the datalabel is when hiding the labels, so I agree that it is a bug.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.crop